# Method lookup in Ruby's interrelation diagram?

Tags: ruby, class, methods

Can someone explain the relation between the Ruby class interrelation diagram and the way method lookup is done in the actual Ruby C code?

Interrelation diagram from https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.3/Class.html:

```
                     +---------+             +-...
                     |         |             |
     BasicObject-----|-->(BasicObject)-------|-...
         ^           |         ^             |
         |           |         |             |
      Object---------|----->(Object)---------|-...
         ^           |         ^             |
         |           |         |             |
         +-------+   |         +--------+    |
         |       |   |         |        |    |
         |    Module-|---------|--->(Module)-|-...
         |       ^   |         |        ^    |
         |       |   |         |        |    |
         |     Class-|---------|---->(Class)-|-...
         |       ^   |         |        ^    |
         |       +---+         |        +----+
         |                     |
 obj--->OtherClass---------->(OtherClass)-----------...
```

and the lookup in Ruby code seems to traverse RClass's `super` member as a *flat* list [here](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/968fcd8346ecb15af8fef76e3b7f7e1be1737a4f/vm_method.c#L730): pseudocode

```
while (!st_lookup(RCLASS(klass)->m_tbl, ...)) {
    klass = RCLASS(klass)->super;
    ...
}
```

Where in the above diagram would the internal [`RClass.super`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/968fcd8346ecb15af8fef76e3b7f7e1be1737a4f/internal.h#L980) and [`RBasic.klass`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/968fcd8346ecb15af8fef76e3b7f7e1be1737a4f/include/ruby/ruby.h#L884) (C structures)
 pointer-arrows be **mapped** ?  Which path would the method lookup take in this diagram? In particular the diagram seems to contain cycles. How is that to be interpreted? What does the `...` in

```
obj--->OtherClass---------->(OtherClass)-----------...
```

mean (singleton of a singleton ?), how is singleton of a singleton accessed in Ruby  and how is it  modeled in the C implementation?

Comment: `RCLASS` appears to be a hash, in which case `RCLASS.super` would raise an exception. What is `RBasic`?. One relation in this diagram that often causes confusion is that the superclass of `BasicObject`'s singleton class is `Class`, but that is the case: `BasicObject.singleton_class.ancestors
 => [#<Class:BasicObject>, Class, Module, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]`.

Comment: I'm referencing the internal C structures of Ruby (have updated the question). For instance. How is the singleton class modeled in respect to RClass.super and RBasic.class ? It seems to be part of the flat klass->super list (?).

Comment: I understand you are referring to the C code but, my C being more than a little rusty, I used the term "hash" whereas it appears to be a structure. I expect the only readers who can answer your question are those intimately familiar with Ruby's underlying C code. That's OK, but be prepared for a lack of helpful answers.

Comment: @CarySwoveland : Maybe I have to reask the question in a different way... What I want is something of a "Internals of what happens on a method call on a C level".

Comment: @CarySwoveland: Tried to summarize my understanding so far in the diagram of the below answer.

Answer (score 1):

I diggged around a bit and the  [`ancestor`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/968fcd8346ecb15af8fef76e3b7f7e1be1737a4f/class.c#L1085) function seem to traverse the RClass.super c-struct member, the same as the [method looup](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/968fcd8346ecb15af8fef76e3b7f7e1be1737a4f/vm_method.c#L730) does. So when I do a

```
class OtherClass end
obj = OtherClass.new
obj.class.singleton_class.singleton_class.ancestors => 
[#<Class:#<Class:OtherClass>>, \
 #<Class:#<Class:Object>>, \
 #<Class:#<Class:BasicObject>>, \
 #<Class:Class>, \
 #<Class:Module>, \
 #<Class:Object>, \
 #<Class:BasicObject>, \
 Class, \
 Module, \
 Object, \
 Kernel, \
 BasicObject]

     BasicObject
          ^           +---------+                 +--------+
          |           |         |                 |        |
      Kernel          | #<Class:BasicObject>      | #<Class:#<Class:BasicObject>>
          ^           |         ^                 |        ^
          |           |         |                 |        |
       Object         |   #<Class:Object>         | #<Class:#<Class:Object>>
          ^           |         ^                 |        ^
          |           |         |                 |        |
          +-------+   |         +--------+        |        |
                  |   |                  |        |        |
               Module |           #<Class:Module> |        |
                  ^   |                  ^        |        |
                  |   |                  |        |        |
                Class |           #<Class:Class>  |        |
                  ^   |                  ^        |        |
                  +---+                  +--------+        |
                                                           |
obj--->OtherClass --->#<Class:OtherClass>--->#<Class:#<Class:OtherClass>>
```

That means the **vertical** arrows in the diagram can be seen as the `RClass.super` c-member traversal.  The **horizontal** arrows on the other hand should be related to `RBasic.klass`,  however the Ruby code seems asymetric.

```
             ...
              |
obj--->   OtherClass
```

When a singleton class is created the former `RBasic.klass` will get the `RClass.super` of the new singleton class.

```
             ...                           ...
            Object                   #<Class:Object>
              ^                             ^
              |                             |                  
          OtherClass                        |
              ^                             |
              |                             |
obj--->#<Class:#OtherClass:0x...> ->#<Class:OtherClass> -+
                                                       ^-+
```

and going one step futher a singleton of a singleton then looks like:

```
             ...                         ...                        ...
            Object                  #<Class:Object>          #Class<#<Class:Object>>
              ^                           ^                          ^
              |                           |                          |
          OtherClass                      |                          |
              ^                           |                          |
              |                           |                          |
obj-->#<Class:#OtherClass:0x...>-->#<Class:OtherClass>-->#<Class:#<Class:OtherClass>>-+
                                                                                    ^-+
```

The meaning/usage of a singleton class is understandable, however there meaning/usage of the metaclasses is a bit esoteric.